# Yii 1.1 action is called 3 consecutive times each time a visitor hits its URL

Tags: yii

I have a specific action that's being called 3 times consecutively each time a user visits the corresponding URL.
I've checked for redirections and don't seem to find any.
The action is not being called directly, I saw the debug callstack and all 3 requests come all the way from index.php and the regular Yii request cycle.
Any ideas of what could be happening?